# How to reset topology for changed webcam resolution (WMF)

Tags: windows, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I have setup a WMF session (built an `IMFTopology` object with a source pointing to a webcam and a standard EVR for screen output), assigned it to an `IMFMediaSession` and started a preview. All is working great.

Now, I stop the session (waiting for the actual stop), change the source's resolution (setting an appropriate `IMFMediaType` via its `IMFMediaTypeHandler`) and then **build a new topology** with that new source and a newly created `IMFActivate` object for the EVR. Also changing the output window's size to match the new frame size.

When I start that new session there's no image (or the image is garbled, or cut off at the bottom - depends on the change in resolution). It is almost as if the new topology is trying to re-use the previously setup EVR and it is not working correctly.

I tried setting that new media type on the EVR when generating a new one, tried to force the new window size on the EVR (via a call to `SetWindowPos()`), tried to get that output node by previously assigned `streamID` and set its preferred input format... Nothing worked - I get the same black (or garbled) image when I start the playback.

The only time the "new" session plays correctly is when I chose back the original source format. Then it continues as if nothing bad happened.

Why is that? How do I fix this?

*Not providing the source code as there's no easy way to just provide the relevant parts*. Generally my code closely follows the sample from MSDN's article on creating a Media Session for playing back a file.

According to MS's documentation the `IMFMediaSession` is managing the start/stop of the source so I'm relying on that when I'm changing the source's video format (otherwise the application fails).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a real new topology, you need to release all MediaFoundation objects (source, sink, topology, and so on).

If not, it can be a little bit complicated.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to get a Topology from the Media Session and release it? Or do I need to keep the Topology pointer around and call a `Release()` on it hoping it would release the one assigned to the Media Session as well?

Comment: Or do I reset the Media Session with a `NULL` Topology and a `MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_CLEAR_CURRENT` flag?

Comment: Yes, you can use MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_CLEAR_CURRENT with NULL. You can also release Media session and recreate it. It is not a long task.

Comment: That's what I expected should have happened. But the preview remains black. Any mode works fine the first time around, but once a topology (and even a session) is re-created by the same exact code - the preview is blank (or shows obvious signs of using the previous mode's stride)

Comment: Try to post a minimal source code that shows the problem.